# How to map different aspects of single scale_color* to different variables in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to simultaneously visualize the mean and error (variance) of predictions in spatial data. One possible method for doing this would be to map the mean to hue and the error to either saturation or luminance. Although I'm doing this in maps, I'll offer a much simpler minimal working example here adapted from ggplot2's documentation.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
dsub <- subset(diamonds, x > 5 & x < 6 & y > 5 & y < 6)
dsub$var <- dsub$x
dsub$diff <-  with(dsub, sqrt(abs(x-y))* sign(x-y))
d <- qplot(x, y, data=dsub, colour=diff)
d + scale_color_gradientn(colours=brewer.pal(7,"YlOrRd"))
```

[image: One variable mapped to color]

What I would like to see, rather than the attached plot, is a version where the luminance or the saturation of the color ramp is mapped to the variable "var" in the data. Ideally, such a plot would include a 2-dimensional legend.

Comment: Not sure if that's what you mean, but you may try `d <- qplot(x, y, data=dsub, colour=diff, alpha=var)`. I have never seen two-demensional legends with ggplot so I doubt that can be easily achieved.

Comment: It appears that ggplot can't do what I'm looking for, though I found an old post from Hadley on a mailing list saying that it easily could. The solution posted by mmk achieves essentially the same effect, and his code for the legend is very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution that's worked for me has been to use a couple layers to represent the data (in this example I'm more or less using hue and value as the two aesthetics, but saturation could be substituted for value by switching the black layer to white), and then generate a custom 2D legend. So, using the data you provided:

```
# main plot
main <- ggplot(dsub) +
  geom_tile(aes(x, y, fill=diff)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(high="red", low="blue") +
  geom_tile(aes(x, y, alpha=var)) +
  theme(legend.position="none")

# 2d legend
diff <- range(dsub$diff)
var <- range(dsub$var)
legdata <- expand.grid(diff=seq(diff[1], diff[2], (diff[2]-diff[1])/20),
                   var=seq(var[1], var[2], (var[2]-var[1])/20))
legend <- ggplot(legdata) +
  geom_tile(aes(diff, var, fill=diff)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(high="red", low="blue") +
  geom_tile(aes(diff, var, alpha=var)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
  theme(panel.background=element_blank(), panel.grid=element_blank(),
        legend.position="none") +
  coord_fixed() +
  labs(title="legend")

# combine plot and legend
library(gridExtra)
plt <- arrangeGrob(main, legend, nrow=1, widths=c(3, 1))
print(plt)
```

[image]

Comment: Would you explain how to change the color of the layer with the alpha mapping? I thought geom_tile(color="my color", aes(x, y, alpha=var)) might do it, but that's giving me an opaque color (no alpha effect visible).

Comment: @Gregory I think you want `fill="mycolor"` -- for geom_tile, `fill` is the color of the cell while `color` is the outline.

Comment: Using a plot as a legend for another plot, awesome! Great solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can also just use `scale_fill_identity()`, convert your data to a valid visual channel range, and then map your values with a function for the fill:

```
df <- expand.grid(H = c(30, 50, 230, 250),
                  S = seq(0, 100, by = 10),
                  L = seq(0, 100, by = 10))

ggplot(df) +
  
  facet_wrap(~ H ) +
  
  scale_x_continuous(
    name = 'Luminance',
    breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 20), 
    expand = c(0,0),
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~., name = 'Hue')) +
  
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = 'Saturation',
    breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 20), 
    expand = c(0,0)) + 
  
  scale_fill_identity() +
  
  geom_raster(
    mapping = aes(
      x = L, 
      y = S,
      fill = hcl(H, S, L)), 
     )
```